# How do I calculate all the cor() between all members of a large dataset using apply instead of for loops?

Tags: r

I have a large set of 10,000 vectors of length about 100 stored in a matrix that I want to calculate the correlations between for all of the set. Unfortunately, on my current computer doing a simple double for loop to produce the correlations is taking forever! Is there a more efficient way I can go about this?

I think I have something like an apply function in mind, but I'm not sure how to implement it with cor().

Comment: 10,000 lists with 100 vectors each? Or 10,000 vectors of length 100? Or a list of 10000 elements where each element is a vector of length 100. What does str(yourdata) look like?

Comment: To clarify: the second: 10,000 vectors of length 100.
$ name1: num  15.3 14.9 15.1 15.1 15.3 ...
$ name2: num  15.5 15.2 15.6 15.4 14.3 ...

Comment: Note 1: The `cor` solution, on a matrix, is the right way to go, but if you're calculating 10K x 10K correlations, that's 100M entries, or approx. 800MB of floating point values. Just be sure that you aren't running out of RAM and swapping (an issue on older machines).  On my modest laptop, the single-threaded 10Kx10K correlation matrix is calculated in about 23 seconds.  The 100x100 matrix is 0.15 seconds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your data into a data frame or matrix and use the built in `cor()` function. Generally, you want to avoid using loops in R.

`cor(yourData)`

Comment: that's what I've done already, but I wasn't sure if there was a better way to somehow run more than one instance of R on different portions of the matrix or something.

Comment: If you are using multithreaded BLAS libraries, then it should run on multiple cores.

Comment: This works pretty perfectly; I guess calling the cor function for each pairwise comparison of the 10k vectors was a really bad idea. It took me 10 seconds compared to the 5 hours I estimated it would take. Thanks to both David and Iterator for their answers and comments.